# log4net works with Xamarin.iOS/Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, log4net

We are using Xamarin Studio to create mobile applications in .NET to some platforms. Our experience show some compatibility problems to use original Log4Net but we're no tried yet the Log4Net Compact Framework (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html).

There's someone with this problem/solution ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works properly! We done the follow steps:

1. include the log4net.dll into References (Figure 1).
2. added the `using log4net;` in using area code.

[image: Xamarin "Edit References" Screen]

Figure 1 - Edit References

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of limitations with the MonoTouch profile. But I managed to get some of the very basic appenders to work. Should give you enough to get started. It's a work in progress, so your milage may vary. Expect bugs!

https://github.com/drunkirishcoder/monotouch-log4net